# Bidirectional grant between rols for Postgres database

Tags: postgresql

If I have 2 roles, `role_a` and `role_b`.

If I grant all from a to b with:

`grant role_a to role_b;`

Then any table, schema, etc created by `role_a` can be queried by `role_b`.

But if I create a table/schema/... with `role_b`, then `role_a` cannot query it...

But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to configure the roles. Basically I have 3 roles:

- role_dev
- role_app
- role_deployment

Dev only exists in CD environment and sometimes I connect and create stuff directly to test re-runable scripts. This role is rather open.

App cannot create tables/schemas but can read/write to everything that exists in that database.

Deploy can create all the tables/schemas.

At the moment I manage this by explicitly granting to the stuff I create, but it's a hassle.

[PostgreSQL group roles](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42377/postgresql-group-roles)

This is the closest I can find but it doesn't appear to work for me.

Comment: there is no bi-directional  security transfer in Postgresql,   Security by design is explicit and one way,  If security can go both ways this opens to data leaks by accidentally granting access to a role.   Not totally sure what you are after,  but maybe you can create some DDL triggers to automate the grant commands.

Comment: PostgreSQLs inability to allow 2 roles at the same level to read data created by each other just forces users to create super users instead of more restricted users. That's far more likely to cause data leaks or accidentally granting unrestricted access to a database, than to allow 2 roles to read data they both created. It's bizarre that you're forced to assume a role before creating tables so that both users can be in that group and gain access to the same data.

Comment: In any case I've worked around this by creating a 'group' and then granting A to B, and using the PreProcessor in dbup to prefix scripts with `set role group_name;` at the start so both A and B will get access to deployed scripts. It's such a hack when I can just create 3 users in SQL Server with specific permissions to do things and it actually makes sense.

Comment: @Philll  WHAT???  Postgresql allows multiple roles to have select insert update delete execute privileges to any object .  Create object aka DDL is different animal and requires specific level of access and some require superusers such as untrusted languages.  SQL sever security module follows Windows access module,  while Postgresql follows Unix model,  and they are very different.  If you are use to one vs the other its difficult to wrap ones mind how the other works...  Using Set Role is not hackish when creating new objects as it simplifies having to go back set ownership of objects.